# Pythonanywhere ModuleNotFoundError No module named mysite

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Hi I've been continuing to get this error on Pythonanywhere trying to run a Django project. Error is with the WSGI file but not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my WSGI file currently:

```
import os
import sys

## assuming your django settings file is at '/home/cole3237/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
## and your manage.py is is at '/home/cole3237/mysite/manage.py'
path = '/home/cole3237/wintergarden_django'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
#
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'wintergarden_django.settings'
#
## then:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The name of the root folder is correct (which seemed to be the problem for anyone whose had a similar problem) so not sure what the issue could be?

Edit: After more looking im wondering if the issue could be the contents of my **init** files in the root and app folders? They are currently blank but app was running fine on my computer's server

Comment: is your Django settings file  at '/home/cole3237/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
and your manage.py is at '/home/cole3237/mysite/manage.py'? Looks like you are completing the Michigan Course. There's a lot of copy-pasting in that course. Be careful!

Comment: Hi its not an assignment but im using a Codecademy guide on launching a Django project using Pythonanywhere. Didn't copy and paste, all the code was just uncommented from what Pythonanywhere already provides in the file initially. And yeah my settings file is located on that path. Thank you!

Comment: what about `manage.py` file?

Comment: After changing your **WSGI** file did you reloaded app?

Comment: Yep manage.py is on the correct path as well. And yeah I've reloaded a few times and continuing to get the error :/